# WebBrowser control stops focus on richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, webbrowser-control, richtextbox

I have problem with WebBrowser component. For some reason, when I click into it, it disables me from setting focus on richTextBox.

I have 2 almost the same forms.

Main difference between first and second form is, that form1 is modifying WebBrowser DocumentText and form2 is using webBrowser to display content of temporary file.

First form is working very well, WebBrowser is not disabling focus on richTextBox. But second form is problematic one. When you click into WebBrowser component, and than back into richtextBox, it never gains focus by Focus() method again :(

Comment: Holy sh*t! Thats the longest 'question' I've seen so far. Maybe you can shorten it down to readable proportions?

Comment: Do you mind code in question or description of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :) I added while loop which waits, until webBrowser.Document property is completely initialized. Than I used webBrowser.Document.CreateElement for creating new html elements, and webBrowser.Document.Body.AppendChild to adding them into document. (I stopped using temporary file...)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and with your answer I came up with an another solution that works for me.

My solution is pretty similar to yours.
I have in a form one RichTextBox which have text and one WebBrowser that display that text (in order to incorporate it into an email).

So, when I change the text in the RichTextBox, with the event handler "TextChanged", I update the HTML into the WebBrowser. But when I click, like you, on the body of the WebBrowser, I can only change one character and the WebBrowser get focus back. Annoying ...

So, after a long search and your answer, I came up with that : I put the focus again on the WebBrowser and then on the RichTextBox. And that works !

```
private void RichTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* your stuff */
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
    WebBrowser1.Document.Write(your_html);
    WebBrowser1.Focus();
    RichTextBox1.Focus();
}
```

And voila, it works !

Hope it will help someone !